# Duplicate request with Kong or Traefik

Tags: microservices, traefik, kong

I'm need send with Kong (Community Edition) one webhook ( request ) for two apis.
The problem is i use one webhook of third parties, and can only specific one URL ( this not negotiation ).

I use in my app Docker, Traefik, Kong and many apis call throug Traefik and Kong, as show in the picture.

[image: diagram of the request]

- I can't send request the Service1 to Service2.
- Create other service is one option but i like avoid this option.
- I would like to solution with Kong but any other option is good for me.

Comment: I am trying create plugin for kong, but i not know what it the best way. [Githuh issue](https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/3811#issue-364994764)

Answer (score 1):

Solve this problem using [goreplay](https://goreplay.org/) and work very well.